# Can't connect to Express server over HTTPS hosted on AWS EC2 through AWS Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

I'm trying to host my API on an AWS EC2 instance and connect to it over my domain configured with Cloudflare (see below) that points to AWS CloudFront.
I can [access it over HTTP](http://stotra-api.spike.codes/api/docs/) but not [over HTTPS](https://stotra-api.spike.codes/api/docs/) (which gives me a 502 Bad Gateway).

[image]

CloudFront is configured to receive HTTPS traffic with an SSL setup by AWS Certificate Manager. It's origin is the Public IPv4 DNS address of my EC2 instance:
[image]

Both the behavior and origin are set to receive both HTTP and HTTPS traffic:
[image]

[image]

EC2 instance has a security group that allows all IPv4 and IPv6 Inbound Traffic and all outbound traffic:
[image]

The EC2 instance is running Express (Node.js) on Ubuntu with all incoming HTTP/HTTPS traffic allowed:
[image]
Requests made over HTTP show on my NodeJS app's logs but HTTPS requests do not.
The Express app is listening on port 80. Should it also be listening on port 443 somewhere?

Thank you so much to anyone who can help! I've been figuring this out for 2 days.

I've double checked the security groups, the Cloudflare DNS settings, the AWS Cloudfront settings, the AWS EC2 instance settings, the certificate manager, and the Express/Node server. I was expecting to connect to the site over HTTPS but cannot do so.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by configuring an Elastic Load Balancer that performend "SSL Termination" by routing all HTTPS requests to port 80 of the EC2 instance.

[image]